# Determine whether the transaction is DTC transaction or not when debugging

Tags: transactions, msdtc

In .Net, is there any way to determine whether the ambient transaction is DTC transaction or not when debugging. I investigated SqlConnection class members but I found nothing. 
thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I prefer to check the [DistributedIdentifier Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactioninformation.distributedidentifier.aspx).

In the immediate window while debugging type:

```
System.Transactions.Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.DistributedIdentifier
```

If the value is Guid.Empty {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  then it is not a distributed transaction (the documentation says null but this is wrong since it is not a nullable type).  Any other Guid value indicates that the transaction has been promoted to a distributed transaction.